# Raycast returning true for each object in my Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

I have an array of prefabs that should be clickable by the player. I have attached this script to the prefab that returns `true` when there is a `Raycast` collision.

```
public bool Clicked()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

In the `Class` that handles the interaction with the prefab `array` I am looping through the array each frame when a mouse click is detected. On each prefab I grab the script component and call the above script. But they all return `true` when I click a single object or they return `false` when I miss.

Here is the interaction script:

```
public GameObject prefab;   
private GameObject[,] pointers;

private float xOffset = -2f;
private float yOffset = -1f;


void Start () {
    pointers = new GameObject[4,4];

    for (int y = 0; y < pointers.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < pointers.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            pointers[x,y] = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(xOffset + x, 0, yOffset + y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            }
        }
    }

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < pointers.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < pointers.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                if (pointers[x,y].GetComponent<Pointer>().Clicked())
                {
                    print ("Clicked!"); //Returns for all when clicked a single object.
                }
                else
                {
                    print ("Not clicked...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense.   `Physics.RayCast` doesn't magically know what object you are calling it from; rather, it should be called only once, and the object that was hit by the ray is returned in the `hit` structure.

Comment: @luqui thanks, that fixed it. Have to get used to this component based system.